# Changing aria-controls attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm having a pretty hard time trying to change the attr of a class using jQuery. 
The line right before the 'count++' is having no effect on .collapseA but the line above that does work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 1;
    $('.collapseTag').each(function (index, value) { 
        var newID = "collapse" + count;
        $(this).attr("id", newID);
        $(this).closest('.collapseA').attr("href" , "#" + newID);
        $(this).closest('.collapseA').attr("aria-controls" , newID);
        count++;
    });
});
```

It's targeting this:

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="" class="collapseA">
```

Thanks

Comment: Should work....

Comment: Seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/d5r2utdL/

Comment: I'll update the code with the rest but I don't think there's anything there that could be breaking it

Comment: I don't see any problems. Could you show us the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: I'll update the code with the <a> that it targets, thanks

Comment: I'm thinking you might not have understood what [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is in that it **goes up** the DOM (parents and ancestors). So could you also include the `.collapseTag` and how it is structured with your `.collapseA` link.

Comment: @ERushforth please add more HTML code.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio thanks for pointing this out, turns out I should've just done (this).attr instead of trying to find the closest, which was itself already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to remove the 'closest' bits because the object was referring to itself already. Derp.

```
$(this).attr("aria-controls" , newID);
```